# logging stdout with python service

Tags: python, unix, ubuntu, service

I'm trying to execute a python script on the background as a service. To do that I used this script that I found on the net.

It's stored at /etc/init/myscript.conf and start with service myscript start

```
description "MyScript"
author "Sherab Giovannini <shaddycls@gmail.com>"

start on runlevel[234]
stop on runlevel [0156]

chdir /root/projects/myscript
exec /root/projects/myscript/script.py | logger
respawn
```

But I didn't find out how to redirect the stdout/stderr to anywhere... I tried with:

```
exec /root/projects/myscript/script.py > some.txt
```

Also with...

```
exec /root/projects/myscript/script.py >> some.txt
```

and every combination that i've found searching on Google...  Sorry if it's a trivial question but I'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: This is much more related to Unix shells than Python. Reading up about [**IO redirection**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) should help. Using `ls missing.file 2>stderr.txt` would redirect STDERR to `stderr.txt` for example.

Comment: I guess it would be.. but the thing here is that i've tried with every combinations that i've seen and no one worked for me :(

Comment: What happens when you run the script from a shell prompt? That is, what happens when you type "/root/projects/myscript/script.py" in the terminal?

Comment: well, the fact is that I changed the original name, but it prints a "test" like "*** output message ***" to check if it's working the stdout logging. On the whole project i'm using the logging python library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I've found this method to run the process and avoid buffering.

```
nohup python -u /root/projects/myscript/myscript.py > /var/tmp/stdout.log &
```

Thanks to all who has contributed on this post.

Answer (score 4):

The file you have installed is an `upstart` script.

Try these options:

```
# Note the full pathname
exec /root/projects/myscript/script.py > /tmp/some.txt
```

or

```
# Note the shell command:
exec sh -c "/root/projects/myscript/script.py > /tmp/some.txt"
```

Confirm that the Python script is executable:

```
$ chmod +x /root/projects/myscript/script.py
```

Examine the system log files to see if there is a useful error message:

```
sudo vim /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog ...
```

EDIT: `upstart` ordinarily directly execs a script, so the shell redirection characters would have no effect. One exception is that `upstart` will invoke `/bin/sh` if there is a `$` or other special character. Apparently `>` doesn't count. So, try this in your upstart script:

```
exec FOO=$$ /root/projects/myscript/script.py > /tmp/output.txt 2> /tmp/error.txt
```

Refs:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man5/init.5.html
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Comment: I tried with the two first options but it doesn't work... it's weird.. if i put a simple print "Hello world!" it doesn't appears

Comment: @Shaddy - Added a fifth suggestion.

Comment: I tried with exec FOO and it says that the process is running but when I do ps aux | grep myscript it doesn't appears. The output isn't on the stdout redirected file... :(

Answer (score 0):

Nohup and & are some tools you are looking for in unix environments with bash.  Nohup make sure that the command doesn't "hang up" when you close the terminal.  and '&' at the end of the statement puts it in the background. '>' and '>>' are for creating new files and appending to possibly existing files respectively.

in bash to run this at the console you would say

```
nohup cmd >>output.txt 2>error.txt &
```

if you are going to put this in a conf script then you can drop the 'nohup'

```
cmd >>output.txt 2>error.txt &
```

Comment: My question is more about how to do that starting with an upstart script.